# What azure service to use for simple c# service - no web

Tags: c#, azure

There is a gazillion types of services in Azure, and I'm having a hard time to choose the correct one.

We're building a service in C# that should periodically check a DB, do some processing and then push REST data to an endpoint outside of Azure.
The service is vital, but it wont be heavy duty, most likely it will do some processing once every 15 minutes and send out some data, then it will sleep and start over again. It's going to send backend data from Azure to a third party 
 on premise server

That sounds simple enough and is probably doable with several types of Azure services, but I need some help to decide which one to go for.
I need some pros and cons of the different types.
Whenever I search the azure documentation most of the services are primarily for for apps/services that expose either a web page or an API, we won't use any of that.

So what Azure project type do you suggest that we choose?
I have looked at "Azure Cloud Service", "Azure Functions", "Web App" etc.

I don't think we will need a full virtual machine, this won't be processing millions of rows each second.

Comment: Take a look at Azure Logic Apps. You might be able to achieve this without writing any code.

Comment: I did start looking at logic apps but it seems abit to hard to do the things that i want. It's not that complex things but they require some fiddling with details. That might be possible with logic apps also but when i researched it (kinda briefly) it didn't seem to give me the fine grained control needed.

Comment: Then Functions is probably your way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your best approach will be a time triggered Azure Function:

```cs
[FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
public static async void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */15 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    await ProcessDB();
    await MakeRestCall();
}
```

Since you want to run it only every 15 minutes, this is ideal!
This will save you a buck while development and deployment is super easy.

Running other solutions (Like a web app) will require you to handle the timer and the environment yourself.
And since it will be always up, you will be paying for the whole time it is up. Even when you don't run your logic.

Comment: Though remember that a Function running on a consumption plan is the one that only costs you when running. Running it on an App Service plan will cost you all the time, even when not running your app.